# Polarization in high energy vacuum non-linearity?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, particle-physics, non-linear-optics

I heard that the vacuum becomes nonlinear at high energies.

What is an intuitive explanation as to why this happens?

For example, in classical optics non-linearitiy comes from material field interactions where the material is a perturbed charged particle modeled as some kind of spring. In quantum mechanics I recal modeling it is an interaction with some other fields lowering/raising operators.

If we expand the polarization term in Maxwell's equations (terms of chi), where do we include high energy vacuum non-linearity?

Comment: _vacuum becomes nonlinear at high energies_ : Please provide a link

Comment: @igael For example on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics or http://www.cft.edu.pl/~birula/publ/NonlStrct.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You need Quantum Electrodynamics (QED) to understand vacuum polarization.  In a nut shell, imagine that the vacuum is filled with virtual electron-positron pairs, and as the high-energy light propagates it interacts with these pairs and they separate creating a polarization-like effect.  In some cases, the electrons-positrons may pop into existence and cause scattering the of light field.

Comment: Okay, is the material that these pairs generate first order (linear) or are they non-linear in terms of expansion of the polarization? Can we just write a small linear suspectability into the Helmholtz equation and be done with it?

Comment: non-linear in terms of expansion of the polarization

Materials are always non-linear, linear response' are just approximations made that generally depend upon the applied field strength.